# Trying to add documents' names from firestore to List<String>

Tags: java, list, google-cloud-firestore

Hy, I'm trying to add documents names from a collection into a List to apply it on a spinner in my android app, and in the Logs I made it's showing the list of the documents but List.size returns me 0 and so the spinner doesn't show anything...
 Here is the spinner setting code:

```
 Spinner listProblem = findViewById(R.id.problemList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, problemTitles());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        listProblem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is the problemList() function:

```
 public List<String> problemTitles() {
    problemList  = new List<String>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(@Nullable Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T> T[] toArray(@NonNull T[] a) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(@Nullable Object o) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsAll(@NonNull Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends String> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(int index, @NonNull Collection<? extends String> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean removeAll(@NonNull Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(@NonNull Collection<?> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }

        @Override
        public String get(int index) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String set(int index, String element) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(int index, String element) {

        }

        @Override
        public String remove(int index) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int indexOf(@Nullable Object o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(@Nullable Object o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ListIterator<String> listIterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ListIterator<String> listIterator(int index) {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public List<String> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    prblmDB.collection("Problems").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int i = -1;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    problemList.add(i++, Objects.requireNonNull(document.get("Prblm Title: ")).toString());
                    Log.d("document title: ", Objects.requireNonNull(document.get("Prblm Title: ")).toString());
                }
                Log.d("list lenth: ", String.valueOf(problemList.size()));
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "ValueEventListener: ", "Done");
            SPB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.i("list value", problemList.toString());
        }
    }).isSuccessful();
    return problemList;
}
```

pblmDB is a FirebaseFirestore element.

And this is the logs I gets when opening the activity:

```
D/document title:: violance
global worming
math class
boringness
sadness
D/list lenth:: 0
D/ValueEventListener:: Done
I/list value: com.example.igi.Solution$2@1cdffeb
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@6036be1
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( XsiavnC7IDSXOlSpvbMLfVbPRtT2 ).
```

Thanks in advance for everyone that may help me!

Comment: Have you tried with `ArrayList` implementation? The list implementation you have `new List<String> {...}` is not implemented properly and I don't understand why you need a custom implementation.

Comment: great, thanks!
it wasn't custom but the default List<String> setup built-in...

Comment: You [can use `ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) with list-based UI widgets, such as Spinner, no problem. What I can see is that you are fetching the documents from your collection successfully as shown in the logs, but you are either not adding your documents to your list correctly, or your list is being initialized or cleared up everytime you run the script; hence, the documents don't appear on your list. Can you check that before anything else?

Comment: I changed it to ArrayList and now it's showing the names of the docs in the spinner at the view but I still can't succeed getting the user's choice with 'getSelectedItem().toString()' nor 'OnItemSelectedListener', they both return null

Comment: Glad to know you made some progress. Can you please update your question with your new code and show any errors that you are receiving? See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164207/spinner-doesnt-show-the-selected-item) to see examples of what this issue can be.